# unable to migrate site from one server to another

Tags: 7, migrations

I have to migrate as site from one server to another. I exported the databaseusing MySqladmin which I also used to import the db on the new server, I copied all files over but I keep getting errors like:
 
**Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/quaaout/public_html/drupal-7.43/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/events.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/quaaout/public_html/drupal-7.43/sites/all/modules/rules/rules.module on line 9**

so I tried loading the latest drupal 7 core 7.43 but I get exactly the same. I then tried to erase that one module `rules` but I got the error for the next, I deleted and the same error would popup for modules `rules`, `apps`, `contentanalysis`,`kwresearch` (which I deleted one after the other) but after the last one I stopped and thought there must be another way to get rid of this error, but how? Please advise!
Thanks!

**EDIT1**

And then since I updated my db version, I tried to call `update.php` but that won't work i.e. the server returns nothing, I get an empty page in firefox and Chrome says: **The  page isn’t working**

**EDIT2**

What I also tried is: **wget --ftp-user=USER --ftp-password=PASS -r ftp://ftp.myolddomain.com/ .** to download the complete site the new host but I still get
 **Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/quaaout/public_html/ftp.quaaoutlodge.com/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/events.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/quaaout/public_html/ftp.quaaoutlodge.com/sites/all/modules/rules/rules.module on line 9** when trying to access the page through the new domain...

**EDIT 3**

Okay, seems like the initial `wget` command didn not catch all the files and I had to re-copy the `sites/all/modules/` and `sites/all/themes`. Seems like I've caught everything now. I'm not sure why this would not have worked initially.
*Manoj Bisht, please return and add your comment as answer to get the credit you deserve, after all, I only started checking for the files within the modules & themes directories after you told me to...*

Comment: Did u try to clear the cache .., if u are not able to clear the cache, then truncate all tables which starts with cache_

Comment: @ManojBisht Is there any alternative way to clear the cache other than from the admin menu?

Comment: Yes, If you have database access, then you can truncate the tables, whose name starts with 'cache_'

Comment: @ManojBisht Okay, So I executed `TRUNCATE cache_bootstrap; TRUNCATE cache_form; TRUNCATE cache_menu; TRUNCATE cache_page; TRUNCATE cache_path; TRUNCATE cache` but this did not seem to change anything.... :( I still get the same error :`Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/quaaout/public_html/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/events.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/quaaout/public_html/sites/all/modules/rules/rules.module on line 9`

Comment: Can u confirm, u have folder and files in the specified location.        /home/quaaout/public_html/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/events.inc    /home/quaaout/public_html/sites/all/modules/rules/rules.module

Comment: @ManojBisht I don't have `modules/` within `rules/` but I do have `/home/quaaout/public_html/sites/all/modules/rules/rules.module`

Comment: @ManojBisht `find /home/quaaout/public_html/sites/ -name "events.inc"` doesn't return anything either

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried backup migrate?

http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate

Make sure you have a vanilla drupal install working perfectly, then copy the sites/all folder from your first server, enable backup migrate and then restore the backup from the first server.

Basically, it will be a lot easier to troubleshoot if you're on a vanilla install and backup migrate is perfect for this.